# How to transform a GUI App to .exe with assets encrypted

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, encryption, libraries

I'm working on a user interface developed on python, problem is, my assets (confidential libraries in particular) need to be encrypted in order not to get reversed-engineered.

I tried using docker, the pyinstaller library and create a setup file.
Despite all my attempts, I get an exe or setup file but libraries are still in clear...

Do you know how I can manage it ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Simply not possible. If you encrypt your code, how are you going to execute it without decrypting it?

Comment: In order for them to be used, the libraries have to be unencrypted.  They're always going to be on the client system in a readable form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers@ Jorn and @TimRoberts , it was actually what I thought at first sight but do you know how companies are doing in order to hide files such as subscription plans, ressource assets for games, etc ? Or more generally how are companies in my case doing ? It gave me a bit of hope aha

Comment: Game resource assets don't need to be protected.  Anybody doing subscriptions does those by phoning home to a web API.  Look, anything you do to shroud your code can be defeated.  They are smarter than you (or I) are.  Very few people are going disassemble a compiled library, but those who want to are going to succeed.